# How To Add Color While Swipe In Android?

Tags: android, listview, swipe, gesture

[image]

Please see the following image attached. I want this to happen when i swipe through an item in my ListView
I have implemented swipe Successfully and when i set :-

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.BLUE);
```

The whole item background changes to blue even when i just touch the item

I want that the color should move with my finger as it happens in any android device.

Please dont post link like duplicate questions, because i have seen those threads and no solution is there please also don't post solutions for implementing swipe in a listview because i have successfully implemented that. i just want this color blue yellow thing to happen when i swipe with my finger. color should move with my finger as it does in any android device

Comment: NEVER USE ALL CAPS NO MATTER HOW IMPORTANT IT IS TO YOU BECAUSE IT'S HARDER TO READ AND DOESN'T HELP

Comment: i have not used CAPS. and this is surely an on- topic question for this site. It is related to android. and if you are asking for attemted solution, then setBackgroundResource() function, i have tried this and all the related background functions, but i have not found a solution for the animation above. It is a listview with a swipe listener and i want this multi coloured animation, and i have tried like hell for a week to accomplish this.

Comment: This is really tough and instead of posting rules and everything, could you please help me ? because i have gone though this website and i have NOT found a solution, or even a little hint for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have implemented a layout file which contains a `listView`, and then for adding images and other stuff for each list item you are using a `customArrayAdapter`.

If so go to the listView `xml file` and add this attribute to the `parent (the outer most) layout`.

```
android:background="@drawable/BLUE"
```

OR

If you haven't implemented a layout file for your list view and you are doing everything in java class extending `ListActivity`, then do like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    list = getListView();       

    list.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.BLUE);
            ....
 }
```

This should help you achieve desired result.

Comment: If you have a android device, could you please go to the calllog and swipe and see the animation, because this is nothing like setBackgroundResource.                                                      It is like when you start to swipe, setbackgroundResource is set to "Orange" and when you move your finger, blue is filled over orange till the position your finger has moved